# Issue with htmlspecialchars - php

Tags: php, xml, encoding, htmlspecialchars

I am using PHP 5.3.3.

I am creating an XML file, but having an issue with the `htmlspecialchars` function.

This works correctly.

```
htmlspecialchars('Day & Night;',ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',false);
```

output - "`Day &amp; Night;`"

However, this does not work.

```
htmlspecialchars('Day &Night;',ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',false);
```

output - "`Day &Night;`"

The generated xml complains, rightly so, about the invalid entity `&Night;`.

I am not sure why it does not get encoded.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `ENT_XML1` instead of `ENT_COMPAT`.

Comment: Have you tried changing the bool to true? Maybe PHP is thinking &Night; is already converted, and is skipping it. From php.net `When double_encode is turned off PHP will not encode existing html entities, the default is to convert everything. `

Comment: Looks like htmlspecialchars "thinks it possible" that `&Night;` is a valid entity. Just a preliminary question: your xml document is really an HTML document or why do you use a HTML* function ? ;-)

Comment: @CodeCaster - It's not available on version 5.3.3.

Comment: @tom-hart It will work, but it will double encode an already encoded character. XML would again be complaining :(

Comment: PHP 5.4 is nearing 3 years of age. Maybe do an upgrade.

Comment: @CodeCaster I would love to, but the company won't.

Comment: But can you use something that is suited for xml instead of html? Like e.g. the XMLReader/Writer classes or depending on the size of the document DOMDocument or ... or ....?

Comment: @VolkerK - I agree. Am looking at alternatives.